# What to do with questions that use rude words or expressions?

Tags: discussion

Not sure about how often it happens but this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96531/how-do-you-log-in-when-you-first-start-the-new-install) started out with a bit rude tone and words. You can also see the same with some answers given on the website.

If I am talking among people that I am familiar with or friends, on a social situation I won't lie an say its all pretty and roses, I curse, to some extend which can be considered much.

We are a sociable community, I understand that during a joke or 2 some words can be written without any issues being raise but on a question being made or an answer being given I find that rude and to some extend offensive.

I know a quick edit could fix that and make the questions "more presentable" to all eyes, but creating them on the first place using rude words or expressions should be be happening.

How to deal with those questions, quick edit them, flag them for deleting, letting a moderator aware of them, warning the user and asking him to refrain from that behaviour?

I am sure that if it was an answer that used rude words it would probably be flagged and deleted. Why not the same procedure for questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3823/what-is-aus-stance-on-profanity, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2764/is-it-smart-to-use-threats-or-insulting-language-when-asking-for-help/

Comment: @jrg sorry to say, all of the above should be dupes of this one ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit, edit, edit. It's your civic duty on the site to ensure content is of the highest quality. While [there have been nit-picks in the past about certain naming conventions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1268/is-it-acceptable-to-replace-linux-with-gnu-linux); However, changing a post to help it form a high quality question is completely the right thing to do.

Comment: Its not about naming conventions, its more something related with rudeness. I'm sure you are aware of the point and that sounds the releasable thing to do but still I find it a bit hard to follow, good manners should be present all the time specially when you are doing something with such a great exposure as writing a question on a site. I agree with you, that it the correct procedure (but sometimes its hard to sallow even if its the right thing to do ;)).

Comment: If a question still might have value but is surrounded by rant, just remove the rant: http://askubuntu.com/posts/96409/revisions

Comment: Good example and answer, thx for the time Marco and Jorge.